# How to stop/pause the execution of a jquery change event from a another onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a jQuery change event which is fired after a textbox was changed, 
 the event is triggered only when the textbox is loosing the focus.
If the users next thing is pressing the cancel button, then the change event is triggered and then the cancel button's `onclick` is triggered too,
but I want to 'kill' the change event and I want it from the `onclick` event.
I know that in jQuery you have some kind of control over events.

```
<input id="change" type="text" />
<input id="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="return cancelEvent(this);" />


$(function () 
{
   $('#change').live('change', function() {
    alert('changed');
   });

});

function cancelEvent(e){
    //kill the change event and continue
    alert('cancel');
    return false;
}
```

There's a solution if I kill then rebind the event : 
 `$('#changeButton').die('change',..).live('change',...);` , 
  but it has to be a more efficient solution for that.

Here's [a jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/imazew/16) where you can play with it!
Hope that's more understandable.
Any contribution to the question are welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by cancelling the change event? It either happens and finishes or doesn't happen. The cancel button click event would occur before or after the change event.

Comment: I know that the live event will occur first.The question is do i have something like stopPropagation in pure javascript, which could be used to prevent to execute the change event from the onclick event?

Comment: It's possible that there are several solutions available. Could you explain a little what it is that you're trying to achieve on a higher level?

Comment: have you looked at the example link above? It's editable. I want to not execute the change event if the user presses the cancel button, but only on that case. Because if the user presses the cancel button, both change and on click event is fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit #1

Seems like I now understand what you want, so ignore my previous answer. Instead, have a look at [this example](http://jsbin.com/emagas/5). Save the value of the control upon focus. Restore the value if cancel button was pressed, even after change was comitted.

## Edit #2

[Same example with one less event handler](http://jsbin.com/emagas/6)

Comment: Basically the same idea of a flag only you store it as a property of the DOM element. Add the overhead of another listener and you get a negative value.

Comment: @kats: I think you did not understand the question well enough. Apparently, OP wants to *undo* the changes when cancel is clicked. Surely you can cancel the change within the change event but you cannot determine if cancel button was clicked from inside that event hence it is useless. So, at minimum you need one listener -- for the cancel button. I added one on the focus event to capture the original value for later use, unlike your example where you blindly clear the value of the control. If can achieve this with one listener I'll +1 your answer.

Comment: To clear or to revert the input value, it doesn't matter. Flag is not necessarily boolean -- you can assign it the new input value in the `onchange` handler. No need to store it in the `data` property. No need for the `focus` event. Anyway, the question is "how to stop/pause the execution of a jquery change event", not how to revert the input value to it's previous state.

Comment: @katspaugh: (i) don't let the question title mislead you, look at the question itself (ii) you *cannot* find out the original value of the control inside the change event. There is a property called defaultValue. If OP wants to restore original value of the control when page loaded that can be used and yes then there will be no need fo focus. If OP wants the cancel button to undo the last typed word then there is no way you can accomplish this from within the change event. If you can determine the value of a control before and after the change inside the change event, enlighten me.

Comment: PS: there is more than one way of doing something. Don't -1 just because it is not how *you* would do it. Whether I use `.data('foo')` or `var foo`... my choice.

Comment: Salman, you can ask this as your own question and I'll gladly explain it to you.

Comment: Of course, it's your choice. As well as my vote for inefficiency is my choice.